# IE7: Flash playing in hidden divs

Tags: flash, html, internet-explorer-7, hide, playback

The scenario is a bunch of divs with flash content inside; clicking on a menu will show / hide these flash-filled divs. Problem is IE7 plays these divs before I "show" them. How can I make sure that IE7 doesn't start the Flash movie until after the div has been "shown"?

Answer (score 3):

Just an idea: maybe you could set your flash embed element when you modify the div's visibility (with JavaScript)?

Something like:

```
<script>
function showFlipFlopDiv() {
  someDiv = document.getElementById("flipFlopDiv");
  someDiv.style.visibility="visible";
  someDiv.innerHTML='<object width="[...]</object>';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Ended up going with a solution very similar to yours as it solved a few other issues as well. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Do you use `display:none;`?

Comment: Then I guess you'll have more luck with Kenji's example.